# Set field as require based in another field's change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress-mvc

I have a DevExtreme form with Razor and I'm trying to apply validation rules. I want to set field as required when another field has value.

```
// This should have a value if the other field has it
socialGroup.AddSimple()
           .ColSpan(3)
           .Label(l => l.Text("Page ID"))
           .DataField(it.Clave)
           .Editor(ed => ed.TextBox().ID("pageId").Value(it.Valor).Placeholder("Page ID"))
           .ValidationRules(v => v.AddPattern().Pattern("^\\d+$").Message("Field must be numeric"));

// This should have a value if the other field has it
socialGroup.AddSimple()
           .ColSpan(3)
           .Label(l => l.Text("App ID"))
           .DataField(it.Clave)
           .Editor(ed => ed.TextBox().ID("appId").Value(it.Valor).Placeholder("App ID"))
           .ValidationRules(v => v.AddPattern().Pattern("^\\d+$").Message("Field must be numeric"));
```

I've tried with Javascript but couldn't make it work.

Comment: What do you mean  `tried with Javascript but couldn't make it work.` because I only saw `C#` code

Comment: That I've tried outside C#, through jQuery.

Comment: The thing is that Razor and DevExtreme generates code in a really complicated way, so even if my jQuery sets the field as "required" (which it does), DevExtreme validator doesn't checks it on submit.

Comment: You can apply a `[RequiredIf]` attribute applied to your property - you can use the [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) library, or you can write your own (refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2))

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not using a model for form, is there another way of using that?

Comment: Why in the world are you not using a model? You could of course write your own script, but that will be client side validation only and anyone can easily overwrite that and post back invalid data. You must always validate on the server.

Comment: Well, I'm not the one who decided not to use a model. Althoug, it's some dynamic stuff, really messy. Anyway, I'm not looking for validate "only" in client side, but I want to be "user friendly" and alert when a field should be fill,